# Having issues login in with devise with a custom view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I load my custom view with this config in `devise.rb`

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

and then this is `my app/views/users/sessions/new.html.erb`

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="login">

        <%= devise_error_messages! %>

        <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

            <div class="login">
                <li><%= f.label :email %> <%= f.text_field :email %></li>  
                <li><%= f.label :password %> <%= f.password_field :password %></li> 
            </div><!-- login -->

            <div class="reset">
                <%= f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true %>
                <%= f.input :password, :required => false %>
                <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
            </div>

          <div class="login">
            <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in" %>
          </div>

        <% end %>

        <%= render "links" %>
    </div><!-- login -->
</div><!-- container -->
```

When I submit it just goes back to the page.

When I disable `scoped.views` it logs in fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot you uncomment this line

```
config.default_scope = :user
```